# How to use Exceptions in Toddish\Verify?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, verify

I'm using [`Verify`](http://docs.toddish.co.uk/verify-l4) as my Auth service in Laravel-4. I managed to successfully install and use it. But I want to maximize its use using its extended Exceptions.

```
class UserNotFoundException {} // User can't be found
class UserUnverifiedException {} // User isn't verified
class UserDisabledException {} // User has been disabled
class UserDeletedException {} // User has been deleted
class UserPasswordIncorrectException {} // User has entered the wrong password
```

I tried using this setup:

```
try {
    Auth::attempt($credentials);
} catch (UserNotFoundException $e) {
    echo "Not Found";
}
```

but didn't work.  But when I use the general `Exception`, it works but I get a general message. How do I use this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those exceptions in the `Toddish` namespace?

Comment: So are you using `use Toddish\UserNotFoundException` before trying to catch it? Otherwise it should be `catch (\Toddish\UserNotFoundException $e)`

Comment: Yes.. Thanks @JasonLewis. The right namespace is `Toddish\Verify\UserNotFoundException`